# Sharepoint Calendar create new view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible to create new calendar view?

I want to show for the logged in user his/her events and also people who have events like `day off`?

scenario: Logged user see his\her events and also user that have events like - day off, sick leave, to be inform who is not avaiable.

I found some clues but still can't get it to work. 
[Clue1](http://sharepointandaspnet.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-show-all-users-schedule-in.html) and  [Clue2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/04/09/sharepoint-group-calendar-adding-default-users/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps to create the calendar:

1. Create a calendar app
2. Modify the view
3. Update the filter to show something like the following

[image]

Basically, the first filter is to show only events created by you (logged in user) and the second filter to show any event that is categorized as Sick Leave and third filter is to show events that is categorized as Day off, and you can add more filters for other criteria.

```
Note: I assumed that these values (sick leave and day off) are coming from the Category field and the values are
```

Comment: Hi, but would I see other users that have i.e. day off?

Comment: yes, you should be able to. That's actually why I am using OR operator so that all matching criteria shows up

Comment: A tryied and I guess it is impossible to do it.